# IIS7 - The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7

I'm trying to setup 2 way SSL on a webservice I manage, and I'm a bit stumped on some behavior I'm seeing.

I decided to first test basic SSL and I didn't even get past this step.

I have a file /load.aspx that just displays the computer name.

When I load this file VIA http, it works just fine. As soon as I try it as an HTTPS url, I get this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /load.aspx

I'm not sure why it's working on port 80 but can't find the file when I use port 443??!

Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: To cover the obvious, your site in IIS is setup to map your application to port 443 right?

Comment: Well, you made me feel like an idiot! I had it mapped to the load balancer, not the specific node which is what I was checking... Thanks...